# Get description of an org-mode link

Tags: org-mode

Is there a function in elisp that will return the description of an internal `org-mode` link?

I would want this to work for any type of supported link:

`[[link][description]]`

`[[description]]`

Etc.

Comment: `org-open-at-point` has some goodies (inside) that you may wish to look at -- i.e., `M-x find-function ...`  I tend to avoid *most* `org-mode` questions directly nowadays because everyone has a different version and the library is under constant development.

Answer (score 8):

I guess you want something like:

```el
(defun get-description-at-point ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((link (org-element-context)))
    (message "%s" (buffer-substring (org-element-property :contents-begin link)
                                    (org-element-property :contents-end link)))))
```

Comment: The command behaves differently depending on whether it is invoked interactively or programmatically. I managed to make its behavior consistent by replacing `buffer-substring` with `buffer-substring-no-properties`.

Answer (score 3):

There exists `(org-link-display-format s)`, which replaces all links in `s` with there description.

For your case you than just need to add the brackets where you want them:

```
(concat "[[" (org-link-display-format "[[link][description]]") "]]")
```

Comment: Thank you! This seems like the sanest answer.

Comment: Works like a charm! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can also use regex to extract the link description:

```
(replace-regexp-in-string "\\(\\[\\[.*\\]\\[\\)\\(.*\\)\\]\\]" "[[\\2]]" "[[link][description]]")
```

will return `[[description]]`.
If you omit the opening and closing braces in the second argument (that is, `\\2`), you will get `description`.

Note: I'm just beginning to use regex, so perhaps there are better solutions to set up the regex.

Comment: `replace-regex-in-string` -> `replace-regexp-in-string`